# Is there a simple way to figure out if two transforms are the same?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I've tried this, but that doesn't work:

```
CATransform3D currentTransform = self.layer.transform;
CATransform3D identityTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
if (currentTransform == identityTransform)
    NSLog(@"the same");
```

I really woulnd like to compare each single field in the matrix ;)
Can I instad compare that somehow as a whole big thing, or do I have to pull out every single value for comparing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`CATransform3DEqualToTransform`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CATransform3DEqualToTransform)